# Search for entities where list contains any value from list in java hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, entity

Lets imagine that I have some Product entity with java.List of tags, as blelow:

```
@Entity
public class Product impements Serializable{
   ...
   private List<String> tags;
}
```

and I have user, that wants to search for products tagged (for example) by any of tags: Car, Motocycle, Plane.

so when it comes to search i have list of tags in my entity, and list of search tags, where all i need is to have at least one of them it in my product's tags list. I don't know how to write such query. thx for help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

before beny23 posted his solution i fixed it by adding

```
SELECT p FROM Product p, IN (p.tags) t where t in (:searchList)
```

but his answer is also correct.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using the following HQL query:

```
session.createQuery("from Product p join p.tags t where t = :tag")
       .setString("tag", tagToSearchFor)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Product implements Serializable{
   ...
   private List<String> tags;

   public boolean contains(List<String> inputTags) {
        for (String tag : inputTags) {
            if(tags.contains(tag)){
                return true;                
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

or you can do 2 foreach, and use

```
if(inputTag.equals(productTag)) return true;
```

Comment: that won't search it in database using hibernate, but thx for answer